# Embedded Wear app not appear on Wear watch

Tags: android, wear-os

My embedded wear companion app is not appearing on the Wear watch (PlayStore -> apps on my phone) anymore. I have

- embedded with: `wearApp project(':mywearapp')`
- same package name
- same permissions
- identical application Ids
- build in release mode

but something must have changed recently because it stopped working. Anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 0):

Still can't say what exactly the reason is it stopped working in Android Studio 4.1 but with Android Studio 4.2 Canary it works again.

Comment: Facing the same issue, my Embbedd watch app is listing on Wear Playstore which has Wear OS version 2.24 but not on the 2.26 and above versions
Fyi i am using Android studio 4.2 RC1
Did yoib find any solution on that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Embedded watch app is not working for me at the moment too.

Comment: If you remove the upgrades of the Wear playstore from the Settings , The app started showing up . idk what might be the issue

Comment: Found the issue . Refer this https://9to5google.com/2021/02/12/wear-os-legacy-apps/ 
we need to submit the watch app to play console